# Checking if a list contains values before calling List.Clear();

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

I was wondering if its "good practice" to check if a list has values before clearing it in .NET? Or is this something thats already checked upon calling `Clear();`?

**Example:**

```
var someList = new List<string>();

// Possibly added some values to the list.

if (someList.Count() > 0) // Checking if it contains values then clearing it.
    someList.Clear();

// ... 

someList.Clear(); // Or just clear it without checking?
```

Which of these is considered "good practice"?

Comment: Checking is unnecessary as the the result is the same regardless whether you check if the list has any items or not.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, if you clear it and theres nothing there it will just move on to the next section of code

Comment: It would be more important to check if the list is null before clearing `someList?.Clear();`

Comment: Also, notice that `Count` is a property of `List`, while `Count()` is a LINQ extension method.

Comment: someList.Clear(); its best prectice..
bcoz if u want to clear list so why we check list have value or not

Comment: Take a step back, and talk us through **why** you want to clear the `List`.

Comment: When in doubt take the smallest clearest code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it would not cost much to check it yourself because `List<T>` has a `Count` property. But it's not needed since [this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,ca7bce81a50b0aeb,references) is the .NET code:

```
public void Clear() {
    if (_size > 0)
    {
        Array.Clear(_items, 0, _size); // Don't need to doc this but we clear the elements so that the gc can reclaim the references.
        _size = 0;
    }
    _version++;
}
```

However, if you don't need to retain the old reference for whatever reason you can always create a new which is the most efficient way:

```
someList = new List<string>();
```

Comment: I saw it, that was a close one lel